Rendering api data to handlebars
I am attempting to pass the results from a Promise.all multi-get request to my handlebars view. The request is functional as it returns results to the terminal, but I cannot figure out how to get the results from the two requests to handlebars.
Router is as follows:
router.get("/chart", ensureAuth, function (req, res) {
  res.render("chart");
});

router.get("/multiple", ensureAuth, function (req, res, next) {
  const apiRequest1 = fetch(
    "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/REFR?apikey="
  ).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  });

  const apiRequest2 = fetch(
    "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/XOM?apikey="
  ).then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  });

  Promise.all([apiRequest1, apiRequest2])
    .then(function (data) {
      var firstAPI = data[0];
      var secondAPI = data[1];

      var combinedData = { firstAPI, secondAPI };
      console.log(combinedData);

    
      res.render('multiple', { combinedData })
      // return combinedData;
    })
    
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Looks like there was a problem: \n", error);
    });
    
});

The following is what is sent back from the request:
{
  firstAPI: [
    {
      symbol: 'REFR',
      name: 'Research Frontiers Incorporated',
      price: 1.92,
      changesPercentage: -2.5381,
      change: -0.05,
      dayLow: 1.795,
      dayHigh: 2,
      yearHigh: 2.24,
      yearLow: 0.9,
      marketCap: 64354176,
      priceAvg50: 1.5046,
      priceAvg200: 1.23735,
      exchange: 'NASDAQ',
      volume: 107372,
      avgVolume: 52760,
      open: 1.98,
      previousClose: 1.97,
      eps: -0.06,
      pe: -32,
      earningsAnnouncement: '2024-08-01T04:00:00.000+0000',
      sharesOutstanding: 33517800,
      timestamp: 1715976000
    }
  ],
  secondAPI: [
    {
      symbol: 'XOM',
      name: 'Exxon Mobil Corporation',
      price: 119.64,
      changesPercentage: 1.5017,
      change: 1.77,
      dayLow: 117.96,
      dayHigh: 119.83,
      yearHigh: 123.75,
      yearLow: 95.77,
      marketCap: 536696665200,
      priceAvg50: 116.928,
      priceAvg200: 108.89025,
      exchange: 'NYSE',
      volume: 14951304,
      avgVolume: 18239392,
      open: 118.3,
      previousClose: 117.87,
      eps: 8.16,
      pe: 14.66,
      earningsAnnouncement: '2024-07-26T04:00:00.000+0000',
      sharesOutstanding: 4485930000,
      timestamp: 1715976184
    }
  ]
}

The following is how my view looks, and I've tried every combination of the each helper as well as the if helper on the handlebars side.
{{#each combinedData}}
    <li>{{firstApi.price}}</li>
{{/each}}

I've also tried the following:
{{#each combinedData.firstApi}}

    <li>{{price}}</li>
{{/each}}


The second template looks OK to me, as long as you are careful about your casing. It should be #each combinedData.firstAPI.

Thanks. Double checked all casing, still nothing. Thank you for the comment though, appreciate it

Turns out it was a callback issue.
router.get("/multiple", function (req, res) {
const apiRequest1 = fetch('https://api.iex.cloud/v1/data/core/quote/aapl?token=').then(function(response){ 
  return response.json()
});

const apiRequest2 = fetch('https://api.iex.cloud/v1/data/core/quote/nvda?token=').then(function(response){
  return response.json()
});

const apiRequest3 = fetch('https://api.iex.cloud/v1/data/core/quote/meta?token=').then(function(response){
  return response.json()
});
let combinedData;

Promise.all([apiRequest1,apiRequest2,apiRequest3]).then(function(data){
  var firstApi = data[0];
  //console.log(firstApi);

  var secondApi = data[1];
  //console.log(secondApi);

  var thirdApi = data[2];

  var combinedData = { firstApi, secondApi, thirdApi };
  console.log(combinedData)
 
  res.render('multiple', { combinedData })
  // return combinedData;
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
});
   //createHtml(combinedData.results);
   //return combinedData;

})

 

